# Scalar Output Tensorflow JS

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow.js

Using a sequential model, how do you take an array of 2d dimensional inputs (a three dimensional input) and have the model perform a prediction on each 2d input, to produce a scalar?  Input shape (boards): [ 153, 8, 8 ]. Output shape (results): [153].

Model:

```
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 8, inputShape: [8]}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units:1, activation: 'sigmoid'}));

// Prepare the model for training: Specify the loss and the optimizer.
model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd'});

const xs = tf.tensor(boards);
const ys = tf.tensor(results);


model.fit(xs, ys, {batchSize: 8, epoch: 10000}).then(() => {
});
model.predict(tf.tensor(brokenFen)).print();

console.log(JSON.stringify(model.outputs[0].shape));
```

Output:

```
Tensor
    [[1],
     [1],
     [1],
     [1],
     [1],
     [1],
     [1],
     [1]]
[null,1]
```

Desired Output:

```
Tensor
[1]
```

If you have any further questions, lmk.

Comment: If your model makes a prediction on each of 8 2d inputs, then you will get 8 outputs, 1 prediction for each of the inputs. Did you want to combine or average these predictions somehow?

Comment: So originally I thought I could just take the average of the 8 outputs and make my own scalar value, however, this means that the network is only examining each rank so the prediction would fail to consider the whole picture.  Thanks for the help tho, I'll look into that idea a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

**A bit of theory ...**

The number of predicted is he batch size of the features given to the `predict` method. To understand better what are the features and the label, let us consider the following.

```
| feature 1 | feature 2 | ... | feature n | Label |
|----------:|----------:|----:|-----------|------:|
|    x11    |    x12    | ... |    x1n    |   y1  |
|    x21    |    x22    | ... |    x2n    |   y2  |
|    ...    |    ...    |  .. |    ...    |  ...  |
```

In the above figure the data has n features, corresponding to n dimensions and the label has a single dimension - for the sake of simplicity and to fit the question. The entry of the model built (first layer) should match the dimension of the features and the output (last layer) should match the dimension of the labels. While training and predicting, we give to the model a bunch of different samples n1, n2. The number of samples gives corresponds to the batch size. The model will return the same number of elements of shape the label dimension.

---

The model has the following `inputShape: [8]`, which indicates that we have 8 features. The last layer has `units:1` suggesting that the label is of size 1. What happens when we predict values ?

```js
const model = tf.sequential();

// first layer
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 8, inputShape: [8], activation: 'sigmoid' }));
// second layer
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1}));

model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd'});
console.log(model.predict(tf.ones([3, 8])).shape) // [3, 1] 3 elements predicted
console.log(model.predict(tf.ones([1, 8])).shape) // [1, 1] single element predicted
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.15.1"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

As the question suggested, the label is predicted from a three dimensional values. In that case, the inputShape will be 3 instead of 8. If `tf.tensor(brokenFen)` has the shape `[b, ...inputShape]`, there will be `b` results values. If you want to have a single value, consider setting b to 1 by expanding the dimension `tf.expandims` or by using `tf.reshape` of a single element of shape `inputShape` - in this case 3.